How do I install addgroup in Redhat UBI?
How can I install the addgroup command? I have verified that shadow-utils has already been installed by default.
$ docker run -it  redhat/ubi9-minimal:latest
[root@367ede092585 /]# rpm -qa | grep -i shadow
shadow-utils-4.9-8.el9.x86_64

[root@367ede092585 /]# add
addgnupghome  adduser  

